# Join Query for autocomplete in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, autocomplete

i want to write a query in mysql php for autocomplete.i have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
`id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`city_name` varchar(44) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;
```

and table2 is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `area` (
`id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`city_id` int(44) NOT NULL,
 `area_name` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2561 ;
```

when user type any word it will search in area table(area_name) and in city table(city_name)...i want to return the result in one field.For example if you type "RAK",it will search in area table.if found it will return city_id and area_name otherwise it will search in city.i need to get cityid , areaid and matched text.how this can be?

Comment: so return different # of columns based on whether the hit is in 'area' or 'city'?

Comment: i want to show area_name and city_name in one column...if area_name is not matched then should search in city_name and will return matched in same column..

Comment: are area.city_id and city.id related?

Comment: yes this is primery and foreign keys..they are linked...

Comment: i want to return like this..[{"id":"12","value":"Arabian Ranches"........}]....now value might be area_name (if hit sucess) or city_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an `OR` clause will cause table scans in both tables. Using a `UNION` will allow indexes to be used:

```
    SELECT 
        city_id,
        id AS area_id,
        area_name AS name,
    FROM 
        area
    WHERE
        area_name LIKE 'searchterm%'
UNION
    SELECT 
        id AS city_id
        NULL AS area_id,
        city_name AS name
    FROM 
        city
    WHERE
        city_name LIKE 'searchterm%'
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start with something like this:

```
select ifnull( area_name, city_name ) from area
   join city on area.city_id = city.id    
   where area_name = <name> or city_name = <name>;
```

I'd need to build a fiddle to test it but the notion of 'failing over' one result to another is there.

Comment: we do not need to use ifnull...we need to check if hit/found or search sucessfull

Comment: The first term will be null if not found - so it will use the second term instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT
    IF(city_name IS NULL ,area_name , city_name) as `Area`
FROM city AS c
LEFT JOIN area AS a ON a.city_id = c.id
WHERE city_name LIKE 'keyword%' OR area_name LIKE 'keyword%'
```

Comment: well it will surely send success if found from either table

Comment: this give me result of those records also which do not contain search term

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.city_name, a.id, a.area_name
FROM
  city AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN area AS a ON a.city_id = c.id
WHERE c.city_name LIKE 'input%'
  OR a.area_name LIKE 'input%'
```

`a.id` and `a.area_name` will be null if the match was only on the city name.